# Refuse to display youtube videos in my website

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube

Hi I develope one website using codeigniter and bootstrap i upload the youtube url in my admin page and get that url in my view page using iframe and load that url. But the youtube video is not showing When I Inspect the website the error is showing like

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ct59FQIbAU' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
>   advertisement:522 GET https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ct59FQIbAU net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

When i inspect this website the url is showing but the video is not showing..  This is that website url  [www.clicx.in/pixelerror](http://www.clicx.in/pixelerror)

In my local server its working

The view code is

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<?php foreach($advertisement as $ad) { ?>
<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $ad->url?>"></iframe>
</div> 
<?php }?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: YouTube only permits very specific URLs to be embedded in other websites. They give you that URL on every video page.

Comment: @ceejoz that for your comment... But i cant understood clearly

Answer (score 5):

**When you're embedding video you shouldn't `COPY` and `PASTE` the video URL on tab**.

You should do something like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7Ct59FQIbAU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

---

When I saw your code there was something like this

[image]

> **I was wonder how it's worked on your localhost ?? :/**

Comment: This is a cms website i add the video url in my admin page and just call that url in my view area... If I use normal coding its working fine...